# How to play MIDI with AudioKit's new AKSequencer

Tags: ios, midi, playback, audiokit, aksequencer

I'm on AudioKit 4.9.1 and can't manage to play a MIDI file with the new `AKSequencer` (replacing `AKAppleSequencer`). No sound playing. Assume that MIDI file AND samples are loaded correctly since they previously worked with `AKAppleSequencer`. Background audio mode capability is also enabled.

Here's the relevant code: (I've also tried both `AKSampler` and `AKAppleSampler` but same result)

```
class MIDIPlayer {
    var sampler: AKSampler
    var legacySampler: AKAppleSampler
    var sequencer: AKSequencer

    init(withSfz sfz: String, orSf2 sf2: String, andMidiFile midiFile: String) {

        self.sampler = AKSampler()
        self.legacySampler = AKAppleSampler()
        try? legacySampler.loadSoundFont(sf2, preset: 0, bank: 0)
        sampler.loadSFZ(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: sfz, withExtension: "sfz")!)

        AudioKit.output = sampler
        try? AudioKit.start()

        sequencer = AKSequencer(targetNode: sampler)
        // sequencer = AKSequencer(targetNode: legacySampler)

        let midi = AKMIDIFile(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: midiFile, withExtension: "mid")!)
        sequencer.load(midiFile: midi)
    }

    func play() {
        sequencer.playFromStart()
    }
```

Is there some difference in how to set up the signal chain that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

With the new sequencer, it has to be part of the signal chain. So, do something like

```
let mixer = AKMixer
sampler >>> mixer
for track in sequencer.tracks { track >>> mixer }
AudioKit.output = mixer
```

and it should work.  Sorry for the delay in seeing this on Github issues.

Comment: I am getting a compilation error:
`Cannot convert value of type 'AKSequencer' to expected argument type 'AKNode?'`

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code, it was just a pseudo code before, this should work better.

Comment: Binary operator '>>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AKMusicTrack' and 'AKMixer?'

Comment: @Bagusflyer make sure you're using the latest AudioKit with the new AKSequencer, not the old one, which has been renamed AKAppleSequencer

Comment: Any news? I'm facing something similar

Comment: @NikLoy have you found a solution?