# How is the AKSequencer setup in AudioKit > 4.8?

Tags: audiokit

An example of how to set up the latest version of AKSequencer is not available, so I had to assume a few things based in the previous version.

I have the following implementation for the `AKAppleSequencer` that works and there's audio output:

```
let track = sequencer.newTrack()
track?.setMIDIOutput(sampler.midiIn)
track?.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: AKDuration(beats: 1), duration: AKDuration(beats: 0.25))
sequencer.enableLooping(AKDuration(beats: 4))
sequencer.setTempo(self.defaultTempo)
sequencer.play()
```

Meanwhile, what I supposed to be enough for the latest `AKSequencer` has no audio output:

```
let track: AKSequencerTrack = self.sequencer.addTrack(for: self.sampler)
track.add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: 1, duration: 1)
sequencer.length = 4
sequencer.loopEnabled = true
sequencer.tempo = 60
sequencer.play()
```

Both cases have the `sampler` connected to the `mainMixer` and are assigned to the `AudioKit.output`.

Since this doesn't work for the latest `AKSequencer`, I thought that the maybe plugging the `AKSequencerTrack` to the `mainMixer` and unplugging the `sampler` to the `mainMixer` could do? But didn't work!

```
mainMixer.connect(input: track)
```

Running out of alternatives! So, after looking for `AKSequencerTrack` found someone else reporting the same issue ([Why is the new AKSequencer not producing any sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527171/why-is-the-new-aksequencer-not-producing-any-sound)), so tried:

```
        mainMixer.connect(input: sampler)
        mainMixer.connect(input: track)
```

Again, no sound! There's also a link to this related topic, which is similar to my previous attempt, which there's no output ([How to play MIDI with AudioKit's new AKSequencer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833495/how-to-play-midi-with-audiokits-new-aksequencer)), but just to make sure changed to use the `AKSampler` and loaded a local sound:

```
sampler.loadSFZ(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "clock", withExtension: "wav")!)
```

Another failure...! There's no sound.

I'm running AudioKit 4.9.5

Just to keep my sanity, there's a method `.play` in AKSequencerTrack, what happens if I call it?

```
track.play()
```

No sound! Ok, what if I change the sampler back to `AKSnareSynth`?

```
let t: AKSynthSnare = AKSynthSnare()
sequencer.addTrack(for: t)
```

Did it play? Nope!

Do I have output at all in non AKSequencer? Yes:

```
        let t: AKSynthSnare = AKSynthSnare()
        self.mainMixer.connect(input: t)
        t.play(noteNumber: 60,
        velocity: MIDIVelocity(127),
        channel: MIDIChannel(1))
```

What about the `.isPlaying` is it Truthy?

```
        for track in self.sequencer.tracks {
             mainMixer.connect(input: track)
             track.play()
             print("> > > > track.isPlaying: \(track.isPlaying)")
         }
```

Yes, the `isPlaying` returns `true`:

```
> > > > track.isPlaying: true
```

But, nope, there's no sound!

I think the `AKSequencer` is a dark box for now and shouldn't be used unless someone posts an example in Github (which I searched for in source-codes but nothing at the time of writing). Or maybe I'm doing something wrong I don't know, just wasted a day of my life trying different things.

Answer (score 1):

@c_booth provided the answer in the following post ( [AudioKit: Using the new AKSequencer with any variety of the callback instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491639/audiokit-using-the-new-aksequencer-with-any-variety-of-the-callback-instruments) )

Seems that the `loop`, `tempo` are set in the `track` not the sequencer itself,

```
// set up a track
let track = seq.addTrack(for: cbInst)
for i in 0 ..< 4 {
    track.add(noteNumber: 60, position: Double(i), duration: 0.5)
}
track.length = 4.0
track.loopEnabled = true
```